# Visual Studio 2010 suddenly slow

Tags: performance, visual-studio-2010, ide, editor

Recently, the editor for VS2010 suddenly became slow when I installed some extensions then uninstalled them.  The program itself is running fine and starts up in seconds.  Jumping around the menus is lightning fast, but editing code, there is a 1 second lag between the keyboard and the editor.

This happens on a brand new console application project with nothing in it.  I have also uninstalled all extensions, resharper etc.  The only extensions remaining are VisualHg, Ankh and Nuget.

I have an i7 with 16 gigs of RAM so hardware is NOT the issue.

Is there some sort of cache or files that VS could have locked onto?

How can I figure out what is causing the issue?

---

Well thanks to @jv42's suggestion, I installed the perfwatson extension and that sorted out the issue.  I've since put some of the extensions back and VS2010 is running better than ever before.

I still don't know what caused the issue.

Comment: I have no answer, but if you think it might come from Visual, you should install http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/fa85b17d-3df2-49b1-bee6-71527ffef441/ PerfWatson so it gets reported to Microsoft.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would find a rollback point before you installed the plug ins.  You could have malware that installed with the plugin but was not part of the uninstall.  It could just be that the uninstall did not remove something it installed that was causing the problem.  It is most likely going to be far faster for you to find a rollback point and start there than to try and figure out what process is causing you the problem and where it is hooked into the registry.

Comment: I think its more likely that the plugins didn't contain malware, but that they may have left dlls/registry keys by mistake.

Comment: I think i covered that as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try resetting your settings from the command line back to the factory default. **Warning** You will lose all your settings!

```
devenv /resetsettings
```

You can back them up, as well as reset, using this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247075%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

finally refer [this](http://devnote.stokemaster.com/2013/01/visual-studio-debugger-slow-to-start-up.html) to fix my problem.

solution is:

`Debug->Options and Settings->Debugging -> Symbols`

change from `All modules,unless excluded` to `Only specified modules`

details:
[here](http://www.crifan.com/visual_studio_2010_suddenly_startup_very_very_slow/)